# Nginx not redirecting to Django

Tags: django, angular, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I am setting up a production server with Angular serving the front end and Django on the back. I got Nginx serving Angular properly but any requests to the backend dont go through and just time out.

I have Nginx serving Angular on port 80 and then Django on port 8800

This is the code I have in place for Django

```
server {
   listen 8800;
   server_name ADDRESS;
   location = /favicon.ico {access_log off;log_not_found off;}

   location = /static/ {
     root /home/ubuntu/django/dbsystem;
   }
   location = /media/ {
     root /home/ubuntu/django/dbsystem;
   }

   location = / {
     include proxy_params;
     proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/django/dbsystem/dbsystem.sock;
   }
 }
```

This is the code I have in place for Angular

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

This is the code for Gunicorn

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/django/dbsystem/
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/django/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 -- bind unix:/home/ubuntu/django/dbsystem/dbsystem.sock dbsystem.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- If I go to ADDRESS it pulls up Angular which is expected
- If I go to ADDRESS/suburl it pulls up the appropriate Angular Route as expected
- If I go to ADDRESS:8800 it loads up the Django (Not found) page since its in debug mode which is expected
- **If I go to ADDRESS:8800/suburl it waits a bit and goes into timeout which is the issue I am trying to solve. This is for both the /media route and all other routes. I dont have/use the static folder route I defined**

Comment: Why do you use `location =` for your Django configuration? Only the first `location` should use the `=` operator.

Comment: `location =` is problem. Try removing this and then check.

Comment: Yes that was the issue, thank you

Comment: I've posted an answer check it out and mark it as accepted if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with `location =` in you nginx configuration. Please remove `=` and it would work.